# Laravel & PHPUnit: Testing other databases than MySQL (Solr / Cassandra)

Tags: laravel, solr, cassandra, phpunit, tdd

i'm pretty to new to TDD and want to do it right from the start.

Unfortunately i cannot find any resources on how to test databases other than MySQL in Laravel.

I'm using Solr with Solarium using [this link](https://petericebear.github.io/laravel-php-solarium-integration-20160725/)

I'm using Apache Cassandra with [`shso/laravel-cassandra`](https://github.com/ShahinSorkh/laravel-cassandra)

MySQL testing takes place with SQLite in memory, but i don't know the correct way to test Cassandra / Solr.

I was thinking of booting up Docker images, but would it be good in PHPUnit / Gitlab CI as well?

Comment: @N69S Not directly testing the database, but testing CRUD actions which require these databases

Comment: You can put those environment variables into either a .env.testing file or the phpunit.xml. If that works you just could start putting stuff in the database and retrieving it, to see if it works.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan yes, that was a thought. But that means that CI should start up a docker container with Solr & Cassandra which could be quite expensive. Is this best practice?

Comment: I think it is. You could cut some of the expenses by pre-building and uploading your own image to GitLab with the container registry, which would speed up the whole CI pipeline.